# Monaco-Editor Some keywords are not highlighted

Tags: monaco-editor, monaco-languageserver

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is the logic of highlighting？ I feel the same language is randomly highlighted.

the version is
"monaco-editor": "0.18.1",
"monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",

Answer (score 0):

Because the highlighting depends on which syntax highlighter is active, which in turn depends on the currently active language in the document.

Comment: thank u, could you elaborate？
Sometimes two identical SQL statements are not highlighted

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7QzN.jpg

Sorry, I don't understand the logic or laws of language active, I feel the same language is randomly highlighted

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure this to highlight

```js
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
   language: 'sql'
});
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd93C.png

Comment: thank u, it not resolve my question, It can be highlighted normally, just not every sql is highlighted